# Mac Appcelerator Studio: An error has occurred

Tags: appcelerator

When trying to run Appcelerator Studio getting this error
[image: error alert]

Ive tried to reinstall Studio with all libraries and caches, nothing works.

OSX 10.10.4 (14E46)
Java 8 Update 60

**An error has occurred.
See the log file**
~/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/.metadata/.log.

```js
!SESSION 2015-08-20 19:53:03.688 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.9.0-ea
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=ru_RU
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/user/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/user/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2015-08-20 19:53:05.671
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2015-08-20 19:53:06.419
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-08-20 19:53:17.256
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/stylesheets/StyleSheetList
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:759)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:272)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:632)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:588)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:540)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:527)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 ... 44 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2015-08-20 19:53:17.680
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: com.aptana.usage.internal.DefaultAnalyticsEventHandler$1
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you need to switch JavaVirtualMachines from *jdk1.9.0.jdk* to *jdk1.7.0_80.jdk* or *1.6.0.jdk*

**/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.9.0.jdk/**