# Error message when launching my app in MAC

Tags: titanium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPoGT.png)

when launching Appcelerator the error is occured

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by one of two issues.
Either your installed JDK version is not compatible or there is a problem with Eclipse.

**JDK Version**

You may have a non compatible version of JDK installed on your system.

This questions was asked before here:
[Mac Appcelerator Studio: An error has occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124180/mac-appcelerator-studio-an-error-has-occurred)

The currently supported versions of the Java Development Kit are listed on this compatibility matrix page:
[Titanium Compatibility Matrix](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Titanium+Compatibility+Matrix#TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-JavaDevelopmentKit)

I suggest you download version 8 of the JDK from:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

The check the path mentioned in this answer to see if you have the correct version:
[Mac Appcelerator Studio: An error has occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124180/mac-appcelerator-studio-an-error-has-occurred)

**Eclipse Error**

There may be a problem with eclipse.

> It is caused by this bug in Eclipse, most likely due to a case where Studio quit or was closed unexpectedly, corrupting a particular file.
>
> Steps to fix:
>   Copy your whole workspace first, so that you are not risking your original files > when you attempt these steps
>
> Delete the file > %WORKSPACE_PATH%/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap, and restart Studio
>
> This will start Studio, but your workspace will most likely be missing your projects. This is okay--you can quickly reimport them
>
> File > Import > Existing Projects....
>
> Select the workspace directory from above, and finish the wizard

[Errors While Starting Studio](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Errors+While+Starting+Studio#ErrorsWhileStartingStudio-Seethelogfile/Users/....)